# How Can I Segment Touching Characters in Python?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, ocr, image-segmentation

I am trying to segment mathematical symbols from images, however, I am not sure how to segment characters that are touching. How could I detect when Characters are touching and then split them? The below screenshot shows what I am trying to achieve.

Presently, I am sorting contours left to right and then using a rect box to segment the characters.  [image]

Comment: Interesting question. Can you provide more details on how you are currently doing your segmentation?

Comment: I am sorting contours left to right and then using a rect box to segment the characters.

Comment: I assume the plan is to feed the results into a network of some kind? In that case I think the best way would be to train the network to recognize touching characters.

Comment: Hmm yeah that did cross my mind actually, however I was hoping there might be algorithms out there that can take a more image processing approach rather than using Machine Learning.

Comment: You need to train your program to recognise the handwriting of the letters you're trying to segment, or train it to recognise whole words, I think. I don't believe that there is much of a graphical difference between a joined "co" and a curly "w" or Greek lower omega, or the letter "d" and a joined "cl", etc.

Comment: that handwriting is aweful. I would not blame any algorithm to fail if someone writes S's like that. some people forget that text is supposed to transfer information in a standardized way.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with standard image-processing tools.

If you're lucky you can resolve a few things with morphological operations but that may as well corrupt valid characters.

You don't know if you have vv or w, cI or d to just name a few examples. So any approach purely based on separating characters is prone to fail.

For your particular example it would make much more sense to recognize `cos` as `cos` and not as `c o s`. `9in` as `sin` instead of `s i n`.

This requires machine learning and some clever semantics.